# converting 64 bits binary 1D vector into corresponding floating and signed decimal number

Tags: matlab

Please let me know how to achieve this as I tried a lot but didn't get the desired result for vector, u=[0;1;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0];
desired output=-108.209
Regards
Nitin

Comment: What makes you think that the binary vector you mentioned corresponds to that decimal number? [The online converter](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=045049048056046050048057) paints a different picture. Also, if you have access the Communications Toolbox, you can use the function [`bi2de`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/bi2de.html). You should mention everything you know about the binary representation, including the standard supposedly used for conversion (IEEE754?), and whether it's encoded somehow.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think your expectation for a correct answer is off. The first bit in a double is the sign. So if you're expecting a negative number, the first bit should be 1. Even if you had your bits backward, it's still a leading 0. There are all sorts of binary to float calculators if you search for them. Here's an example:
http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=4C378941600D5BC0

To answer your question for how to do this in Matlab, Matlab's built in function for converting from binary is `bin2dec`. However, it's expecting a char array as an input, so you'll need to convert to char with `num2str`. The other trick here is that `bin2dec` only supports up to 53 bits. So you'll need to break it into two 32 bit numbers. The last piece of the puzzle is to use `typecast` to convert your pair of 32bit integers into a double. Put it all together, and it looks like this:

```
bits = [0;1;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0];
int1 = uint32(bin2dec(num2str(bits(1:32)')));
int2 = uint32(bin2dec(num2str(bits(33:64)')));
double_final = typecast([int2 int1],'double')
```